# How do you print out the division calculated for each pair of variables on the same line?

Tags: java, variables, operation

UPDATED

I am trying to make a grid that shows whether variable numOne and numTwo are divisible or not together.  Basically, I want the outcome to look like this

```
       1          2          3         4        ....
1   tResult    tResult    tResult   tResult     ....
2   tResult    tResult    tResult   tResult      ....
3   tResult    tResult    tResult   tResult     ....
4   tResult    tResult    tResult   tResult    ....
5   tResult    tResult    tResult   tResult    .....
```

tResult represents (x%y) or (1%1) (2%1) and so on. And also, the grid can be larger or small depending on the input user writes for numOne and numTwo.

What I am trying to figure out is how layout this grid by using System.out.print() for each line, printing out the numOne in the beginning followed by the x amount of tResults, except the first one.  This is probably not the best method out there, but since I am a beginner, the only thing I can do is print out stuff.
Also, the problem I am having is that I am not getting the results I want.

The code I have is:

```
            int x=1;
    int y=1;
    int numOne; int numTwo;
    Scanner input=new
            java.util.Scanner(System.in);

    //First value
    System.out.println("First number:");
    numOne = input.nextInt();
    while (x<=numOne){
        System.out.print(" ");
        System.out.print(x+" ");
        x++;
    }

    //Second value
    System.out.println("Second number:");
    numTwo=input.nextInt();
    System.out.println(numTwo);
    int tResult=(x%y);
    while (y<=numTwo){
        System.out.print(" ");
        System.out.print(y);
        y++;
        System.out.print(tResult);
```

Comment: if you don't want multiplication, why are you doing `tResult * numOne`?

Comment: `System.out.println(var1 + " " + var2 + " " + var3 ....)` Is this what you are trying to do?

Comment: I want the number of tResult variable to increase depending on what the value the user inserts. I have added more code in my description to make it clearer.

Comment: @user2843235 +1 for updating question and giving clarity, and make sure you give this much of clarity in your all questions, so you can get quick and more responses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Updated answer:**

Following is one way to achieve what you are trying to achieve using while loop.

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    int numOne; int numTwo;
    Scanner input= new java.util.Scanner(System.in);
    //Get First value
    System.out.println("First number:");
    numOne = input.nextInt();
    //Get Second value
    System.out.println("Second number:");
    numTwo=input.nextInt();
    input.close();
    int x=1;
    int y=1;
    System.out.print("     ");
    while(x<=numOne)
    {
        System.out.print(" [  x="+ x +" ] ");
        x++;
    }

    x=1;y=1;
    while(y<=numTwo)
    {
        System.out.println();
        System.out.print("[y="+ y +"]");
        while(x<=numOne)
        {
            int tResult=x%y;
            System.out.print(" [("+ x +"%"+ y +")"+tResult+"] ");
            x++;
        }
        y++;
        x=1;
    }
}
```

Sample output:

```
First number:
4
Second number:
5
      [  x=1 ]  [  x=2 ]  [  x=3 ]  [  x=4 ] 
[y=1] [(1%1)0]  [(2%1)0]  [(3%1)0]  [(4%1)0] 
[y=2] [(1%2)1]  [(2%2)0]  [(3%2)1]  [(4%2)0] 
[y=3] [(1%3)1]  [(2%3)2]  [(3%3)0]  [(4%3)1] 
[y=4] [(1%4)1]  [(2%4)2]  [(3%4)3]  [(4%4)0] 
[y=5] [(1%5)1]  [(2%5)2]  [(3%5)3]  [(4%5)4]
```

Comment: didn't work. it calculated unless i did something wrong.

Comment: @user2843235 I didn't get you, Can you be more specific? Or update in your question what didn't work.

Comment: Ahh, I feel like you did understand it. For your case, tResult variables should have printed out 4 times but yours just printed out 8888.

Comment: @user2843235 You want to print the value of `tResult` or you want to print `tResult` as a string? Code in my answer will print addition of two variables.

Comment: @user2843235 can you please update your question with sample input and sample output?

Comment: @user2843235 Please have a look at `Update1`, If are not looking for this then Please ask different question with more details.

Comment: Updated it. I changed the question and the description.  I hope it's clearer now.

Comment: @user2843235 Have a look at updated answer, And let me know if you require anymore information about above answer.